# point custom .com.ar domain to github pages

Tags: redirects, domain-registrar, github

...yet another question about github pages and custom domains, sorry. I couldn't find a solution in other questions, I think that's very specific to my registrar. Also, I'm not a webmaster or sysadmin, this would be simply my online resume (CV).

I have a domain from Argentina's nic.ar registrar => mydomain.com.ar

Currently, my domain is delegated to a free web hosting where I was experimenting with. I want it to point to my current github page myuser.github.io, **but I simply don't know how.**

Github gave me 4 IP addresses in order to redirect:

- 185.199.108.153
- 185.199.109.153
- 185.199.110.153
- 185.199.111.153

but my registrar only accepts hostnames:

[image]

What options that are free and simple do I have to make my .com.ar domain point to my github page?

Comment: You are not in the correct menu of your registrar. You should not (necessarily) change the delegation; that is the list of nameservers authoritative for your domain, you should see with DNS provider `hostinger-ar.com` how you can change the **content** of your zone, in order to be able to add 4 `A` records to point `www` and the domain itself to the 4 IP addresses you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patrick Mevzek already told you a possible solution in a comment. I want to provide you with another one with more benefits [using the free version of Cloudflare](https://blog.cloudflare.com/secure-and-fast-github-pages-with-cloudflare/). That's how I have all my GitHub pages.

[image]

First of all, you need to create a free account on Cloudflare and, after that, [add your domain](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/201720164-Step-2-Create-a-Cloudflare-account-and-add-a-website). Use the hostnames provided at this point (follow the instructions provided) to point your domain to your Cloudflare account. They should be something like this:

- cass.ns.cloudflare.com
- lou.ns.cloudflare.com

Secondly, you need to point Cloudflare to Github so, go to Cloudflare's DNS menu and create the A records [as you've been told in the official guide](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain/#configuring-a-records-with-your-dns-provider).

[image]

Now you can easily setup redirects (www to non www), SSL certificates, firewall rules, cache, etc.